# Is there a commonality in German "lächeln" and "lachen" which is not in English "to laugh" and "to smile"?

Tags: word-choice

I found a song on youtube last week. [immer lacht](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bkj3IVIO2Os). In the video the young women is smiling not laughing and it's been a couple of decades since I was in Germany. So, I mistakenly thought that *lachen* meant "to smile",  not "to laugh".

But this got me wondering if *lachen* and *lächeln* being spelled so similar and also sounding so similar results in any overlap in meaning for Germans that doesn't arise with the English words "to smile" and "to laugh".

Are there any English/German bilinguals that could answer this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The words *lachen* ("to laugh") and *lächeln* ("to smile") are close etymological relatives. This is the reason of them being so close in spelling and pronounciation. *lächeln* is derived from *lachen*, it is a [diminutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive) form of *lachen*.

While in German the noun diminutive is formed by adding the ending *-lein* and potentially transforming the core vowel to an Umlaut, the way of forming the verbal diminuitive by transforming the core vowel into an Umlaut and changing the verb's ending to *-eln*, is a common pattern, expressing small, difficile, or insignificant action (for instance in *blinzeln*, *kitzeln*, *witzeln*, *fiedeln*, *rätseln*...) and some of such verbs also have the "non-minimised" version productive - like *schnitzen*/*schnitzeln*, *hacken*/*häckseln*.<sup>1</sup>

German is not alone in conceptualising "to smile" as a small form of "to laugh", as a [look at etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=smile) shows: Romance, Celtic, and Slavic languages tend to use a diminutive of the word for "to laugh" to mean "to smile" (such as Latin *RIDERE* "to laugh;" SUBRIDERE "to smile"), perhaps literally "small laugh" or "low laugh."<sup>2</sup>

So, besides the fact that there might be a sort of small laughing which is close to a big smiling, there is no overlap in the meaning of the two words in German which would not also exist in English.

But into the German language a closer conceptual proximity of "to laugh" and "to smile" is inscribed than into the English language. I guess the words are so close that most native speakers are intuitively aware of their close etymological relationship.

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to [tofro](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/20363/tofro) for clarifying this in a comment.

<sup>2</sup> Credits to [Carsten S](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/3237/carsten-s) for this information.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach thanks for your answer. I preferred the song when I mistook it for smile. It seemed more serene and melancholic to be smiling 'putting a brave face on', whereas laughing seemed more forced and in denial.

Comment: Of course there is overlap. *Jemanden anlächeln* or *sich jemanden anlachen* may both refer to flirtation. In the former case it's entirely pragmatic. You can put your Duden back into the holster. *Schmeicheln* would incidentally express a very similar notion. *Sich einschleimen* might also belong here, as do *like* and *to give somebody looks*.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @jonathan scholbach's great answer I'd just like to add something about the use of "lacht" in this song. Lyrics: https://www.songtexte.com/songtext/stereoact-feat-kerstin-ott/die-immer-lacht-2b1fe476.html

The song lyrics plays with a pair of opposites that has been well-known in literature since ancient times, "lachen" und "weinen". So that might be an additional reason why "lachen" is used here. What the text basically says is that the person is "laughing" all the time when in company, but she's unhappy and "crying" when she's alone. In this context, it doesn't matter much if "lachen" or "lächeln" is meant, it's just about her trying to appear happy and bubbly to others.

The video visualized this slightly differently from what the song text says. If you look at it from a language standpoint, "die immer lacht" clearly means "who always laughs", not "who always smiles".

Comment: the song may be about the sun in the best tradition of poetry, *die Sonne lacht* being a well known idiom for sunshine, which might incidentally translate as "the sun **smiles** upon us". Likewise, *strahlen* is both "shining" and making a "happy" face; *Strahleman* (sunny boy) possibly a kenning since sun anthropomorphism was predominantly male in Indoeuropean myth. On the other hand, the song could as well be about a *pretty woman*. Schlager is intentionally ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

vielleicht bin ich völlig falsch
für mich ist "lächeln" nie mit "Geräusch" verbunden
lachen - laughing - ist nie? ohne Ton
kichern (als kleine Form von Lachen) - giggel ... ist hörbar, wenn auch leise